# Pre-Collision Object Staging

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-engine, game-physics

I am making a billiards game. Currently, when one ball collides with another at high speed, the collision is not always calculated correctly. I know what the issue is, but I'm not 100% sure how to fix it.

Say two balls are traveling with these velocities:
[image]

More often than not, when the collision is detected, the balls will have some overlap between them that looks like this:
[image]

Currently, my physics engine will handle the collision at this moment in time. This will not give the desired result since this is NOT where the balls collide in reality - balls don't go through one another. So, we need back up the balls to where they really collide. That would look like this:
[image]

I am looking for an efficient algorithm that would help me do this. Currently, I have a very naive and inefficient method - I move both balls to their locations just before the collision and take very small steps toward the moment of collision. Of course, this is very inefficient. Here is what it looks like:

```
void CBallCollision::StageCollision()
{
    double sumOfRadii = mBall1->GetRadius() + mBall2->GetRadius();

    mBall1->SetCenter(mBall1->GetLastLocationOnTable().first, mBall1->GetLastLocationOnTable().second);
    mBall2->SetCenter(mBall2->GetLastLocationOnTable().first, mBall2->GetLastLocationOnTable().second);
    double timeStep = 0.008;
    double tolerance = 0.1 * min(mBall1->GetRadius(), mBall2->GetRadius());
    int iter = 0;
    while (GetDistance() > sumOfRadii)
    {
        double xGoal1 = mBall1->GetX() + mBall1->GetVelocityX() * timeStep;
        double yGoal1 = mBall1->GetY() + mBall1->GetVelocityY() * timeStep;
        pair<double, double> newCoords1 = mBall1->LinearInterpolate(xGoal1, yGoal1);
        
        double xGoal2 = mBall2->GetX() + mBall2->GetVelocityX() * timeStep;
        double yGoal2 = mBall2->GetY() + mBall2->GetVelocityY() * timeStep;
        pair<double, double> newCoords2 = mBall2->LinearInterpolate(xGoal2, yGoal2);

        double dist = (pow(newCoords1.first - newCoords2.first, 2) + pow(newCoords1.second - newCoords2.second, 2));
        if (abs(dist - sumOfRadii) > tolerance)
        {
            timeStep *= 0.5;
        }
        else
        {
            mBall1->SetX(newCoords1.first);
            mBall1->SetY(newCoords1.second);
            mBall2->SetX(newCoords2.first);
            mBall2->SetY(newCoords2.second);
        }
        iter++;
        if (iter > 1000)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't put an upper bound on the number of iterations, the program crashes. I'm sure there is a much more efficient way of going about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may be interested in this: [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php?print=1) - it is basically your problem + solution in one single article.

Comment: But you can calculate exactly when they collide or not collide given the constant velocity vectors and their positions. You don't need to check collision step by step.

Comment: In short, if you use vectors to see if paths crossed, you can do a collision detection at any speed.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I implemented this method last night. One thing I was a bit confused about it how they used the dynamic-static collision algorithm for two moving circles. It was a bit unclear. Instead, to check if balls A and B collide, I first test assuming A is dynamic and B is static, and then test again assuming B is dynamic and A is static. It seems to work fine, but I'm not sure it's equivalent which makes me unsure if my method has edge cases I don't account for.